Property change not detected in child component
I'm currently stuck on some data refreshing issue with Vue3 & xState.
(I don't think that xState is involved in this issue, but I'd rather mention it)
Data is not refreshed in child component when data is changed by external process (in my case, xState status change).

In my parent component, displayed data [OUTSIDE Statuses] is up to date, after external change on state.context.documents
In my child component, updates [INSIDE Statuses] are not displayed, except if I change anything else and it re-draws DOM.

Why child component is not detecting data change ?
It tastes like a proxy issue but I do not succeed in finding the right way to embed my data in sub component with a full-reactive behavior.
Parent component
<div class="results-container">
  [OUTSIDE statuses]: {{state.context?.documents?.map((doc) => doc._detailLoaded)}}
  <DocumentList :documents="state.context?.documents" />
</div>

const searchMachine = useSearchStore().actor;
const { state } = useActor(searchMachine);


DocumentList Child component:

  [INSIDE Statuses]: {{documents?.map((doc) => doc._detailLoaded)}}

  <!-- Element Plus ElTable component -->
  <ElTable :data="documents"
        @expand-change="loadDetails">

    <!-- Date -->
    <ElTableColumn
      class-name="dr center"
      fixed
      width="160"
    >
      <template #header>
        <span class="date">{{ $t('publish date') }}</span>
        
      </template>
      <template #default="scope">
        <Field
          :t="$t('publish date')"
          :v="scope.row.publishDate.getLocaleDate('medium')"
          c="date"
        />
        
      </template>
    </ElTableColumn>


    <!-- Expandable -->
    <ElTableColumn
      :fixed="expandable"
      :v-if="expandable"
      :width="50"
      class-name="expand"
      type="expand"
    >
      <template #default="scope">
        <ItemDetails
          :document="scope.row" />
      </template>
    </ElTableColumn>
  </ElTable>
</template>


...

// Search Machine context
const searchMachine = useSearchStore().actor;
const { send } = useActor(searchMachine); 
...

const properties = defineProps<{
  documents: DocumentModel[] | undefined;
}>();
const loadingStatuses = computed<boolean[]>(() => {
  return properties.documents?.map((d) => d._detailLoaded ?? false) ?? [];
});

const loadDetails = () => {

  // Will change
  send({type: 'COMPLETE_DOCUMENT'});

};


When I expand ElTable row, DocumentDetails do not displays right. I've to close & reopen collapsable part to display it.

Deep analysis shows me that it could be due to deep reactivity issue on my documents array. I've found a workaround at this step by including an hash of my array in property of sub-component. But it redraws the entire component (that triggers new UX problems). Quite bad way to fix the problem
